# Using Pillow image.merge, getting 'Image' object has no attribute 'merge'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Just trying to do a simple program to create an image and take the color channels from another and swap them around and save. But I'm getting an error that Pillows Image has no attribute merge, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.merge

```py
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("test.tga")
newImage = Image.new("RGBA", image.size, 1)

ir, ig, ib, ia = image.split()
nr, ng, nb, na = newImage.split()

newImage.merge("RGBA", (ia, ig, nb, na) )
newimage.save("testoutput.tga")
```

Comment: Compare [`PIL.Image` functions](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#functions), which must be explicitly called, like `merge`, vs. [`Image` class functions](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#the-image-class), which directly work on an `Image` object, like `split`. That further explains the correction in Mark's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
result = Image.merge("RGBA", (ia, ig, nb, na) )
```

@HansHirse makes an excellent point in the comments (thank you) which is worth promoting and reiterating to a more prominent position in an answer...

> Compare [PIL.Image functions](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#functions), which must be explicitly called, like `merge`, vs. [Image class functions](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#the-image-class), which directly work on an Image object, like `split`.