# In PIL getting 'Image' object has no attribute 'merge' error message- Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook, python-imaging-library

Trying to complete change the colors of an image using the Image.split() function changing the r,g,b values then recombining them with .merge()

I checked this post too [Using Pillow image.merge, getting 'Image' object has no attribute 'merge'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66347765/using-pillow-image-merge-getting-image-object-has-no-attribute-merge)

which looks exactly like my issue but didnt help...

I've tried looking the issue up and following documentation for a couple hours and still getting the error.  I've tried restarting the module too as well as copying chunks of others code because it's a coursera course and am not having any luck

```
`import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageEnhance


# read image and convert to RGB
image=Image.open("readonly/msi_recruitment.gif")
image=image.convert('RGB')



# build a list of 9 images which have different brightnesses
enhancer=ImageEnhance.Brightness(image)
images=[]
for i in range(1, 10):
    images.append(enhancer.enhance(i/10))

# create a contact sheet from different brightnesses
#first_image=images[0]
contact_sheet=PIL.Image.new(first_image.mode, (first_image.width*3,first_image.height*3))
x=0
y=0

#create first blue image:
blue_one=images[0]
#splitting color channels
r,g,b = blue_one.split()
r=100
g=100
b=100
result = blue_one.merge("RGB", (r, g, b,) )




display(result)`

This is the message I'm getting

`
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-b586316626f8> in <module>
     32 #result = blue_one.merge('RGB', (b,g,r))
     33 #blue_one = blue_one.merge('RGB',(r,g,b))
---> 34 result = blue_one.merge("RGB", (b, g, r,) )
     35 
     36 

AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'merge'
`
```

Edit: This is how I created this first blue image

```
   #1st blue image
        # decrease reds 
r, g, b = image.split()
r = r.point(lambda i: i * .1)

# Recombine back to RGB image
result = Image.merge('RGB', (r, g, b))

result.save('result.png')
blue_images.append(result)
display(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This line makes 3 single channel (`L` mode) PIL Images:

```
r,g,b = blue_one.split()
```

You can check by running:

```
print(r)
```

which gives:

```
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=256x256 at 0x12A242710>
```

You then run these three lines that make `r`, `g` and `b` into integers:

```
r=100
g=100 
b=100
```

Now they are no longer `PIL Images` and you cannot merge them.

---

If you mean to fill an image with a solid colour like lime green, there is no need to split the channels and you can use:

```
im.paste((0,255,0), box=(0,0,im.width,im.height))
```

Comment: How is what I did different than the first solution you gave for the question here? Is it because I've turned them into integers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59320564/how-to-access-and-change-color-channels-using-pil

Comment: Yes. Did you mean to fill the image with rgb(100,100,100) ?

Comment: ...I think so...I am doing the same project as the asker in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68784629/using-pil-to-adjust-color-saturation-of-list-of-images-i-receive-no-errors-but?answertab=trending#tab-top) post so I am first trying to 
 understand how the color is even changed

Comment: Looking at your edit -no I am meaning to change the hue of the image

Comment: I'm now quite confused about what you really want fo do. Your question changes the *brightness*, but your comment says you want to change the *hue* (i.e. colour) and you have linked to an animated GIF! What do you actually want to do? And do you want 9 variants of the same, single image or are all *"frames"* supposed to be different basic, starting images?

Comment: [here is the goal](https://uxjsvscw.labs.coursera.org/files/readonly/assignment1.png)

[this is the original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhDz7.png)

Comment: I can't see the goal - it's behind a login.